# Heroku ImageMagick gives error: ArgumentError (no images in this image list):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to crop an image using ImageMagick (rmagick gem) on a Heroku rails server. Here is my code:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 include CarrierWave::RMagick
 #include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!(x, y, w, h)
        puts "officially cropped!"
      end
    end
  end

  version :standard do
    process :crop
    resize_to_limit(2000, 2000)
  end

end
```

Here is the error it keeps throwing at me:

> 2016-03-03T12:18:22.236892+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 296ms 2016-03-03T12:18:22.243033+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2016-03-03T12:18:22.243040+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (no images
>   in this image list): 2016-03-03T12:18:22.243041+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/uploaders/photo_uploader.rb:21:in `crop'
>   2016-03-03T12:18:22.243046+00:00 app[web.1]:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the ImageMagick buildpack. Heroku does not include the necessary files for rmagick without it. https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick

This will also require you to run multiple buildpacks. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Comment: Is this the buildpack you are talking about? https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick

Comment: Yes that is the one, I meant to include it.

Comment: I tried doing this but the server crashed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832328/installing-imagemagick-buildpack-on-heroku-rails-cedar-14