# Installing ImageMagick Buildpack on Heroku Rails Cedar 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick

I am trying to install this 3rd party Heroku buildpack for ImageMagick: https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick

I tried running this command:

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick
```

Then I repushed my app to the server, and did a restart. The app didn't work. So I tried restarting the dyno using this command:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

I get this response, and cannot run the app unless I remove the ImageMagick buildpack:

> Scaling dynos... failed  !    Couldn't find that formation.

Any idea how I can get ImageMagick properly installed?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this yesterday. I don't know about your specific instance but in mine, I had added this build pack after my others. It needed to be before.

In addition, I needed to purge the cache. My remote is called `production`, so I did the following:

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git
heroku repo:purge_cache --remote production
heroku buildpacks:remove https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick --remote production
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick --remote production
```

Then I pushed my repo to `--remote production` and it worked.